# Strange jquery animate behavior in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a simple animation which works fine in Firefox, now I tested it in all other different major browsers and it behaves weirdly there unfortunately.

The .truck element should slowly fade in while moving from left to right and at the end fade out again.

On all browsers except FF it stays right and moves a bit backwards..

Maybe you have an idea what the problem might be.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwuJd/)

html:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">              
        <div class="animation"></div>
        <div class="truck"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.panel-body {
    position: relative;
}
.animation {
    background: green;
    width: 788px;
    height: 145px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.truck {
    background: black;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -34px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var truck = $('.truck');
    truck.css("opacity", "0");
    truck.animate({
        right: 15
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 5000
    })
    .animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000)
    .delay(3000)
    .animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000);

});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the title a kind of Paradox?!

Comment: you are right, I changed it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing

```
truck.animate({
            right: 15
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 5000
        })
```

change it to `left`
will work for all the browser

```
truck.animate({
            left: 500
        }, {
            queue: false,
            duration: 5000
        })
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YwuJd/2/)

give a check

Answer (score 1):

You change "right" on function but you don't set first value of this property. For example I set "`right:100%`" and it's work fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/zJt3T/

Comment: The answer of lopa works better in my context. But thank you as well for your help.